# How to direct to Google Play app using PHP from mobile browser?

Tags: php, android

I can go to Google PLay desktop version using **header()** in php but I want to go to my application in Google PLay app when I click on a link from mobile browser. I have searched a lot but I haven’t reached anything helpful. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redirect the same way you'd do for non-mobile browser. It's because on non Android devices mobile version would be shown for the browser and for Android devices with Market app, in most cases user will open this link in native Market app, instead of browser.

Comment: I tried using header("location: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.earth"); to redirect but it gets me to the Google Play desktop version also from my Android phone.

Comment: The redirection is based on your browser `user agent`, check if you're requesting the desktop version of the website or try with a different android web-browser like firefox.

Comment: @Tuga Thank you. It works with Android built browser and it gives me the choice to open my application from Google Play app. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play's mobile version isn't a website, its a app itself. So you can't redirect user there, instead they can install it from Google Play's website.

EDIT:

Forget what i said, read the comments below.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, check Marcin Orlowski answer and you'll see why.

Comment: I remembered when you click on Google Play link it brings "Open With.." dialog and you can choose Google Play or Browser now, thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the user-agent of browser, just do this.

```
<?php
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua,'android') == true) {
//if(stripos($ua,'iPhone') == true) {
echo 'android';
    header("location: market://details?id=com.truecaller&hl=en");
}
else echo "not android";
?>
```